# Filter array of object with unique value from duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
var  Error-dictionary = [
   {
      code:599,
      MSG:'unknown' 
   },
   {
      code:404, 
      MSG:'not found'
   },
   {
      code:599, 
      MSG:'unknown'
   }
]
```

I want something like this:

```
[
  {
     code : 599,
     count:2,  
     MSG : 'unknown', 
     code :404,
     count:1,
     MSG : 'not found' 
  }
]
```

and this need to push into 
`$scope.alerts` as a MSG

Error code and MSG are dynamic

Comment: what do you do if your MSG is different for the same error code ?

Comment: iterate array and create new object. Please show what you tried ... this isn't a code writing service

Comment: That is also one more case @dlght

Comment: you can count the number of appearences easily, but how do you deal with the different error codes ? take the most common or the first ?

Comment: Is the example output supposed to be an array of two objects?  That's not a valid javascript object with two copies of the same property.

Comment: I would suggest you to remove the duplicate occurences and leave the array as you show it. This way you would spare the headache of dealing with all the cases that appear in the process ;]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of an specific property in a array of objects, by using underscore.js. Nice and easy!!!

```
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var dict = [
      {code: 599, MSG: 'unknown' },
      {code: 404, MSG: 'not found'},
      {code: 599, MSG: 'unknown'}
    ];

    var res = _.groupBy(dict, function (d) {
      return d.code;
    });

      var dictArr = []; 

        for(var key in res) {

            var code = key; 
            var value = res[key]; 
            var MSG = value[0].MSG; 
            var count = value.length; 
            dictArr.push({ code : code, MSG: MSG, count: count  }); 

        }; 

        console.log(dictArr); 


  };
</script>
```

Comment: this does not result in what the OP is asking :]

Comment: have to know what codes exist and will iterate array for each code ... not very efficient or scaleable

Comment: You can't group by msg also. You just need to for-loop this one time to create the object he wants

Comment: Now does the result reflect exactly what he does ask. I was not aware he needed so much handholding.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp object that uses the error code and message as keys. Then map that temp object to output array

```
var tmp = {}, res =[];
data.forEach(function (item) {
    var tmpKey = item.code + item.MSG;
    if (!tmp.hasOwnProperty(tmpKey)) {
        tmp[tmpKey] = angular.copy(item);
        tmp[tmpKey].count = 0;
    }
    tmp[tmpKey].count++;
});

for( var key in tmp){
   res.push(tmp[key]; 
}
$scope.errors = res;
console.log($scope.errors);
```

Comment: angular.copy(item); and $scope.errors = res; is angular?